# Setting up a relational DB for event logging

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am a bit rusty with my SQL since I have not worked with it beyond basic querying of existing databases that were already setup.

I am trying to create an event logging database, and want to take a "extreme" approach to normalization. I would have a main table comprised of mostly 'smallint' fields that point to child tables which contain strings.

Example:

I have an external system that i would like to enable some logging in via SQL, user fills in some key parameters which build and insert/update statement and gets pushed to the logging tables so they can be viewed at a later time if they need to know what XYZ value was at runtime, or sometime in the past.

I have a main table which consists of:

```
SELECT [log_id] - bigint (auto-increment) PK
      ,[date_time] - smalldatetime
      ,[cust_id] - smallint FK
      ,[recloc] - char(8)
      ,[alert_level] - smallint FK
      ,[header] - varchar(100)
      ,[body] - varchar(1000)
      ,[process_id] - smalint FK
      ,[routine_id] - smallint FK
      ,[workflow_id] - smallint FK
  FROM [EventLogs].[dbo].[eventLogs]
```

All of the 'smallint' field point to a child table which contains the expanded data:

Example:

```
SELECT [routine_id] PK/FK
      ,[routine_name]
      ,[description]
  FROM [EventLogs].[dbo].[cpRoutine]


SELECT [process_id] PK/FK
      ,[process_name]
      ,[description]
  FROM [EventLogs].[dbo].[cpProcess]
```

My goal here, is to have the external system do an update/insert statement that reaches all these tables. I have all the 'smallint' fields linked up as FK's currently.

How do i go about crafting the update/insert statements that touches all these tables? If a child table already contains a key-value pair, i do not want to touch it. The idea of the child tables is to house repetitive data there and assign it a key in the main logging table to keep size down. Do i need to check for existence of a records in child tables, save the index number, then build my insert statement for the main table? Trying to be as efficient as possible here.

Example:

I want to log the following from the external system:

```
- date_time - GETDATE()
- customer_number - '0123456789'    
- recloc - 'ABC123'
- alert_level - 'info'
- header - 'this is a header'
- body - 'this is a body'
- process_name - 'the process'
- routine_name - 'the routine'
- workflow_name - 'the workflow'
```

Do I need to create my insert statement for the main table (eventLogs) but check each child table first and add missing values, then save the id for my insert statement in the main table?

1. Select process_id, process_name From cpProcess where process_name = 'the process'
2. If no values returned, do an insert statement with the process_name
3. Now query the table again to get the ID so i can build the "main insert statement" that feeds the master log table
4. Repeat for all other child tables
5. final insert statement looks something like:

SQL code:

```
INSERT INTO eventLogs (date_time, cust_id, recloc, alert_level, header, body, process_id, routine_id, workflow_id)
VALUES('2017-12-31', '1', 'ABC123', '3', 'this is a header', 'this is a body', '13', '19', '12')
```

It just seems like i am doing too much back and forth with the server checking for values in the child tables to do my insert....

The end goal here is to create a friendly view that pulls in all the data assigned to the 'smallint' keys.

Answer (score 0):

You're close:

1. Select process_id from cpProcess where process_name = 'the process'
2. If no values returned, do an insert statement with the process_name, get ID through IDENT_CURRENT, SCOPE_IDENTITY, or IDENTITY (or use a subordinate "load" procedure and get the ID from an output parameter).
3. Repeat for each child table until you get the values required to do your final insert into [eventLogs].

This works fine if it is a relatively low speed process. As you increase the speed you can have issues, but if you are doing INSERT only, as you should, it still isn't terrible. I've used SQL Server Service Broker in the past to decouple processes such as these to improve performance, but that obviously adds complexity.

Depending on the load you might also decide to build aggregate tables in a fact/dimension star so that the INSERT OLTP process is segregated from the SELECT OLAP process.

What you're seeing is the complexity involved in building a normalized data structure. You're approach "to take a "extreme" approach to normalization" is often bypassed because it's "too hard". That doesn't mean you shouldn't do it, but you should weigh the ROI. I have made decisions to just dump everything into a log table such as this below in the past where there were only going to be perhaps less than ten thousand records at any given time. You just have to look at the requirements and make the best choice.

```
CREATE TABLE [log].[data]
  (
       [id]          INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
       , [timestamp] DATETIME DEFAULT sysdatetime()
       , [entry]     XML NOT NULL
  );
```

One option that I frequently use during the build out phase of a design is to build placeholders behind adapters as shown below. Use the getter and setter methods ALWAYS and later, when you need better performance or data storage, you can refactor the underlying data structure as required, modify the adapters to the new data structures, and you've saved yourself some time. Otherwise you can end up chasing a lot of rabbits down holes early in the project. Often you'll find that your design for the underlying structures changes based on requirements as the project moves forward and you'd have spent a lot of time on changes. Using this approach you get a working mechanism in place immediately.

Later on if you need to collapse this structure to provide better performance it will be trivial compared to constantly changing the structure during design (in my opinion).

Oh, and yes, you could use a standard relational table. I use a lot of XML in applications and event logging because it allows ad hoc structured data. The concept is the same. You could use your top level table, just with the [process_name], etc. columns directly in the table and no child columns for now.

Just remember you should NOT allow access to the underlying tables directly! One way to prevent this is to actually put them in a dedicated schema such as [log_secure], and secure that schema to all but admin and the accessor/mutator methods.

```
IF schema_id(N'log') IS NULL
    EXECUTE (N'CREATE SCHEMA log');

go

IF object_id(N'[log].[data]', N'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [log].[data];

go

CREATE TABLE [log].[data]
  (
       [id]          BIGINT IDENTITY(1, 1)
       , [timestamp] DATETIMEOFFSET NOT NULL -- DATETIME if timezone isn't needed
         CONSTRAINT [log__data__timestamp__df] DEFAULT sysdatetimeoffset()
       , [entry]     XML NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT [log__data__id__pk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id])
  );

IF object_id(N'[log].[get_entry]', N'P') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE [log].[get_entry];

go

CREATE PROCEDURE [log].[get_entry] @id      BIGINT
                                   , @entry XML output
                                   , @begin DATETIMEOFFSET
                                   , @end   DATETIMEOFFSET
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT @entry
        FROM   [log].[data]
        WHERE  [id] = @id;
    END;

go

IF object_id(N'[log].[set_entry]', N'P') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE [log].[set_entry];

go

CREATE PROCEDURE [log].[set_entry] @entry       XML
                                   , @timestamp DATETIMEOFFSET = NULL
                                   , @id        BIGINT output
AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [log].[entry]
                    ([timestamp]
                     , [entry])
        VALUES      ( COALESCE(@timestamp, sysdatetimeoffset()),@entry );

        SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    END;

go
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have never built a system like this, just worked with and understood the basics of its structure in a past life. I know what i need done, i just don't know what tools are available to me in MSSQL to accomplish it since i haven't used SQL on this level for a long time. Looking into your suggestions now to try and get something working, i would rather have a well thought out solution that can scale because i know we will be hammering on this thing hard once its up and running reliably.

Comment: How many records per time period do you expect to have submitted to the table? What is the archival period?

Comment: If i remember correctly, it was in the low millions within a year. But i don't need retention for that long just yet, 3-6 months should be adequate since the current application is for debugging and issues shouldn't be hanging around that long. I do however see this evolving into a larger model over time so all external systems can communicate and use data from one source, so i want to take my time and build this out with the future in mind.